# ROS Answers SE migration: android_core

Tags: ros, android-core, rosjava, android, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know of any step-by-step tutorials where I can use android_core (I want to publish data from accelerometers on the phone to a robot). I can't find any that work.

After spending countless hours with android_core and rosjava, I'm ready to throw in the towel.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92521/android_core/) by [larry](https://answers.ros.org/users/7911/larry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might not be the answer you were expecting, but if you only want to get accelerometer/gyro data from your phone into ROS have you ever checked the "ROS Sensors Driver" app in the Play Store?

Have you already tried this tutorial? http://wiki.ros.org/sig/Rosjava/Android%20Development%20Environment

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2013-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [larry](https://answers.ros.org/users/7911/larry/) on 2013-10-20**:
yes, but it is out of date, especially the github pages. I'm not really sure about the app. It's not obvious how to use it, and more importantly, I'm not just outputting sensor data; I'm fusing it and then outputting that.